# Anonymous user encountered while accessing rest-api with simplejwt

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am able to obtain access and refresh token using SimpleJWT. I have a custom decorator which tries to identify type of user from user profile. Code fails here because it can not find authenticated user.

I have repeatedly tried to get user via debug mode in VS Code but not successful.

Here is my settings.py

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken', # Add this line
    'rest_auth',                # Add this line
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount', # we will not be using this but not keeping this entry results in error while deleting user. A known issue https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/issues/412
    'crispy_forms',

    'users',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        #'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ),
}

REST_USE_JWT = True

'''
#https://www.techiediaries.com/django-rest-framework-jwt-tutorial/
JWT_AUTH = { 
    'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': True,
    'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER': 'custom_jwt.jwt_response_payload_handler',
  # 'JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER': 'custom_jwt.jwt_payload_handler',
  # 'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'Bearer',
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(seconds=300)
}
'''

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True,

    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,

    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',

    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',

    'JTI_CLAIM': 'jti',

    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM': 'refresh_exp',
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
}

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

SITE_ID = 1
```

Here is user model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.conf import settings

class User(AbstractUser):



    username = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.email)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'ADM'),
        (2, 'GEM'),
        (3, 'JET'),
        (4, 'CAT'),
        (5, 'SPR'),
        )
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    dob = models.DateField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads', blank=True)
    user_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES,default=1,unique=False)
```

Here is the view i want to access

```
@method_decorator(user_is_ADM,name='dispatch')
class HelloView(APIView):

    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request):
        content = {'message': 'Hello, World!'}
        return Response(content)
```

Here is the custom decorator which is troubling

```
def user_is_ADM(fun_c):
    @wraps(fun_c)
    def wrapped(request, *args, **kwargs):


        if request.user.profile.user_type == 1: <---throws error here
            return fun_c(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            raise PermissionDenied
    return wrapped
```

I am able to get access/refresh token pair from simplejwt using http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/ with username and password supplied. But when I try to access HelloView using http://127.0.0.1:8000/core/hello/ (core being app name) with accesstoken (of course, with Authorisation: Bearer......), the decorator comes in picture. Now this decorator needs request.user to verify whether the user is 'GEM' or not. Problem is no user has logged in hence system gives me error that 'Anonymous' user has no attribute 'profile'. Even if , I login as prerequisite, same error is faced. I am new to django.

How to resolve ? Any alternate suggestion ?

Comment: How are you making your requests? Through postman?

Comment: yes, through postman. I tried the debug console offered by VS Code also but not successful.

Comment: and you login to get the token? or do you just make a request to /api/token to get it?

Comment: i get the token using /api/token then use it to access hello view. Result - anonymous user issue
i login using /rest-auth/login/, get the token using /api/token, then use it to access hello view. Result = anonymous user issue.
As soon as I remove @user_is_GEM decorator, everything is fine, i get 'hello world' message.

Comment: When you remove the decorator, Is there a user or is it still an anonymous user?

Comment: Decorator part is required to check type of user. If I remove decorator, just token is sufficient to successfully run and get 'hello world' message. But issue is I want to check type of users for restriction to certain views. Seems I need to have UserProfile for checking type of user but I am not even able to get User in my decorator.

Answer (score 0):

With lot of struggle (which is good for a beginner like me), debugging, trial and error, I learned a lot and solved on my own. I took extensive help of debugging facility of VS code to arrive at solution and I would recommend all newbies to get used to that.

Here is the solution.
- I imported the UserProfile model using

```
from users.models import UserProfile
```

then modified decorator as follows:

```
def user_is_ADM(fun_c):
    @wraps(fun_c)
    def wrapped(request, *args, **kwargs):
        # 1 = ADM
        #u = UserProfile.objects.get()
        #if(request.user and request.user.is_authenticated()): 
        if(request.user and request.user.is_authenticated) :   
            user_data = UserProfile.objects.get(user_id = request.user.id)
            u = user_data.user_type


            if  u == 1:
                return fun_c(request, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                raise PermissionDenied
    return wrapped
```

**Verification**

- called /api/token/ with valid username and password having. For trial, user type = 'ADM'
- got the access token.
- Then postman is used to call the helloWorld API with AccessToken (of course, with Authorization: Bearer 'access
  token')
- now the decorator came into play and as I have deliberately provided user having, it perfectly validated.
- finally, I could successfully get 'hello world' message.

**Conclusion**
 - I have seen posts where users are struggling to get authentication using middleware. Someone please validate my approach. Of course, @Naveen Jain and @dirkgroten both deserve credit as they have guided me passionately. True to the spirit of Stackoverflow and developer fraternity.

Thanks for your interest...